# flume getting error while updating data in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, flume

I need to run flume in separate machine which is not part of HDFS data node or name node and it has to read data from Kafka and store it in HDFS running in a separate cluster. Can it be done? I am getting errors related to hadoop jar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Flume requires Hadoop jars for **HDFS Sink** since you are reading data from **kafka** and storing back in **HDFS**.

Please add all hadoop related jars in the classpath and then rerun it.